# What is this (in kitchen plumbing)!

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I took apart part of the drain system underneath my kitchen sink to clear a clog, and found this guy. Not sure if someone in my house dropped it down on accident, or it’s been there a while, or broke off something, or what!

[image: item]

Comment: Hard to tell the size - can you take a picture of it next to a ruler? What does your sink use for a drain stopper if you want to fill it with water?

Comment: Tool for making a line (straight or curved) of equally spaced holes in leather?

Comment: it is an eating utensil ....  a cheese fork .... https://img1.etsystatic.com/152/0/8327973/il_340x270.1132400983_twex.jpg

Answer (score 5):

It is an Olive stick for eating Olives.

[image]

Comment: Although I agree I thought of olive fork also, we like more than 1 line answers, I believe it is an olive fork because it is just like mine I have both green and black ones to identify the type of olives in the jar. The 1 line may have been the reason there was a down vote.+